# Simple Calculator Application in C#

Tags: c#, math

I have two quick question about this simple calculator application I am trying to build in C#. (not homework by the way) I am trying to get the MessageBox.Show message to show in the multiply and add sections of my code, but they don't seem to be displaying even if I enter a negative value. The application just seems to do the math anyways. Also, this may be a dumb one, how do I get rid of the label5 text that appears in the application with out deleting it in the properties window?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AddMultiply
{
     public partial class AddMultiply : Form
{
    public AddMultiply()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtFirstValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double firstValue;
        double secondValue;
        double answer;

        while (double.TryParse(txtFirstValue.Text, out firstValue) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The value(s) entered must be > 0");
        }
        while(double.TryParse(txtSecondValue.Text, out secondValue) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The value(s) entered must be > 0");
        }


            answer = firstValue + secondValue; 
            lblAnswer.Text = answer.ToString();

    }

    private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double firstValue;
        double secondValue;
        double answer;

        while (double.TryParse(txtFirstValue.Text, out firstValue) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The value(s) entered must be > 0");
        }
        while (double.TryParse(txtSecondValue.Text, out secondValue) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The value(s) entered must be > 0");
        }


            answer = firstValue * secondValue; 
            lblAnswer.Text = answer.ToString();

    }

    private void lblAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblAnswer.Text = ""; //tries to get rid of "label5" text in application, but fails to do so
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I dont see any label named label5 in your application

Comment: Yes the while loop is causing the value to be always true and not allowing the control to pass through. Replace it with If and it should work.

Comment: I tried changing the while loops to if statements and the same thing keeps happening @CHash_Mike

Answer (score 1):

1)you should change the while to "if":

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double firstValue;
        double secondValue;
        double answer;

```
    if (double.TryParse(txtFirstValue.Text, out firstValue) == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The value(s) entered must be > 0");
    }
    if(double.TryParse(txtSecondValue.Text, out secondValue) == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The value(s) entered must be > 0");
    }


        answer = firstValue + secondValue; 
        lblAnswer.Text = answer.ToString();

}
```

2) where is Ladel5 ? It doesn't seem to be exist...

Comment: When I change them to if statements, the message still doesn't pop up when I enter a negative value and try to add or multiply.

Oh and label5 is lblAnswer. label5 is the text that appears every time I run the program. I would like to make the label5 text not appear without deleting it in the properties window.

Comment: hey, sorry, i wasn't next the computer. the double.TryParse(txtSecondValue.Text, out secondValue) == false checks if the tryparse had succeeded, and yes it was. because of that you didn't got the messageBox. what you should do is if (secondValue > 0) (for example).  About lblAnswer - i tried to reproduce what you said but for me it works fine...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: the code: 'double.TryParse(txtSecondValue.Text, out secondValue)' returns true if it succeeded to put some value to the variable secondValue. if the function **TryParse** failes to do so, it returns false and the variable **secondValue** remains empty. Becuase the function always succeed to put some value in **SecondValue** whether it's positive or negative value it always returns true and the code: ' if (double.TryParse(txtFirstValue.Text, out firstValue) == false)' is always false - this is the reason you don't get to the **MessageBox**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to show the MessageBox then the value is less than 0:

```
if (n1 < 0 || n2 < 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Value less than ZERO ", "Value less than ZERO",MessageBoxButtons.OK , MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

As for getting rid of the label you can try :

```
label5.Visible = false;
```